# Using an SKAction to change position of an SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, position, skaction

I have a game in which I need an SKAction that moves the position of a SKShapeNode 64 units up. This is the code for the object that I need to move up.

```
var rect = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize(CGSizeMake(200,200))
rect.position = CGPointMake(0,0)
```

I want to make it so that every few seconds, 64 units is added to the rect's y value. So:

```
rect.position = CGPointMake(0,64)
```

And Then

```
rect.position = CGPointMake(0,128)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to smoothly animate your `rect` over 1 second of time, you could try something like this:

```
let moveRect = SKAction.moveToY(rect.position.y+64, duration: 1)
moveRect.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseInEaseOut // This line is optional
rect.runAction(moveRect)
```

The second line is added to ensure an ease-in ease-out movement, but it is not necessary.

Is this what you where looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
let move = SKAction.moveTo(y: rect.position.y+64, duration: 1.0)
move.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.easeInEaseOut
rect.run(move)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while word != ""{

if word[word.startIndex] == "R" {

let moveSpriteToRight = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x+128, y: sprite.position.y), duration: 1)

sprite.run(moveSpriteToRight)

} else if word == "D" {

  let moveSpriteToDown = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x, y: sprite.position.y-128), duration: 1)

sprite.run(moveSpriteToDown) 

} else if word == "L" {

let moveSpriteToLeft = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x-128, y: sprite.position.y), duration: 1)

sprite.run(moveSpriteToLeft) 

} else if word == "U" {

let moveSpriteToUp = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x,
 y: sprite.position.y+128), duration: 1)

sprite.run(moveSpriteToUp) 
}

word.remove(at: word.startIndex)}
```

It's part of my code.I can't use SKAction many times.  For example, if the word = "ULD", then the sprite should move along the path up (U), then left (L) and down (D). And each time through the gestures the user creates new trajectories, the termination of recording gestures occurs through touchesEnded. Sprite them must perform each time.
But my sprite in simulator changes position to Down in this example and all.